# Is there a way to prove continuity without using epsilon-delta?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I'd like to know if there is an easier way of provining continuity instead of using the epsilon-delta criteria? I cannot understand it because it's way too complicated for me...

There is no workaround? Like converting the series to a function, then prove convergence on the function. If the converted function is continuous, the series will be continuous as well. Something like that would be possible?

Or there are other ways which are a bit easier?

Sorry for asking a question like that but I couldn't find anything on the internet. I really hope there is another way...

Comment: I have never heard of "constant continuity of series" and searching online has brought me nothing using that phrase. Perhaps you mean [uniform convergence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformConvergence.html)? Please state the definition of constant continuity that you are using.

Comment: Will R Oh yeah that's what I meant :P
Got troubles translating some words correctly, especially in that context.

Comment: Are you talking about a numerical series or a function series? Uniform convergence doesn't make sense in the context of a numerical series.

Comment: Example would be $f:[0,\infty)\ni x\mapsto \frac{x^{2}}{x+1}\in \mathbb{R}$. Now I realize, I shouldn't have said series since this is a function.. Anyway, would like to know if it would be possible without epsilon delta.

Comment: So you just want to know how to prove continuity without using $\epsilon$-$\delta$?

Comment: If so, I undeleted my answer which will give you an avenue to do just that

Comment: What is your math background? This is rather important for someone trying to answer your question. @Wavelet gave you a nice discussion, but if you don't know about metric spaces then I suspect what he says misses the mark (a mark that you have not provided us). Indeed, I would be rather surprised if someone who knows about metric spaces would be fuzzy about basic elementary calculus epsilon-delta continuity ideas, but I suppose it could happen if someone rushed into advanced topics before appropriately learning lower level topics. (I see now that he's added some stuff about the real line.)

Comment: What's so difficult about the usual definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on @Dave L. Renfro's comment, I am inclined to include a detailed example, since that might help more than or at least supplement my explanation. This one is moderately tricky, if I remember and execute this correctly (it's been awhile).

Say $f(x)=x^{2}$ and we want to find a general $\delta$ that holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for alll $\epsilon>0$ we have that $\lvert x-a \rvert<\delta$ implies that $\lvert x^{2}-a^{2} \rvert<\epsilon$.

Now, to start, note that we can factor our inequality 
$$
\lvert x^{2}-a^{2} \rvert=\lvert x-a\rvert\lvert x+a\rvert 
$$
now notice that we have
$$
\lvert x-a \rvert<\delta \text{ and } \lvert x-a\rvert\lvert x+a\rvert<\epsilon
$$
so we can write 
$$
 \lvert x-a\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{\lvert x+a\rvert}$$
and furthermore, say that we were to assume $\delta$ satisfies
$$
\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\lvert x+a\rvert}
$$
and 
$$
\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\lvert x+a\rvert} \implies  \lvert x-a\rvert\lvert x+a\rvert<\epsilon
$$
but notice that $\delta$ depends on $x$, and ideally, we want $\delta$ to be a function of $a$ and $\epsilon$ only. To sidestep this issue, we assume that $\delta <1$ then by choosing a $\delta \leq 1$ we have that $\lvert x-a \rvert < 1$ whenever $\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta$.
Now note that $\lvert x-a \rvert \leq 1$ is equivalent to saying that  $x$ is within a distance of $1$ of $a$ which implies that for $\lvert x+a\rvert$ we have 
$$
\lvert x+a \rvert +\lvert x-a\rvert<1+\lvert x+a\rvert  \implies \lvert x+a \rvert <\lvert 2a \rvert +1
$$
so now we have a bound on $\lvert x+a \rvert$ which only depends on $a$ so we can write
$$
\lvert x-a\rvert < \delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{\lvert 2a \rvert+1} \right\}<\frac{\epsilon}{\lvert x+a\rvert}
$$
Which shows that $f(x)=x^{2}$ is continuous for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Kouba's [THE CALCULUS PAGE PROBLEMS LIST](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/ProblemsList.html) has a lot of worked examples (see under "limit of a function using the precise epsilon/delta definition of limit"). I used to use this web site with classes I taught in the late 1990s --- I can't believe it's still around!

Comment: A remark: this doesn't show that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous (the last paragraph may seem confusing).

Answer (score 8):

This answer is about the continuity of functions, since the comments under the question indicate that the question was really about continuity of functions rather than convergence of series.

The continuity of a function $f:A\to\mathbb R$, 
where $A \subseteq \mathbb R$,
is usually *defined* in terms of limits of the form $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$.
Limits of functions are usually *defined* using quantifiers over
variables $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

The reason the definition is important is that it applies to every function
you could ever look at.
It is possible to write the criteria for continuity differently
so that they still apply to every function, either by proof or by definition.
[This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96324/whats-wrong-with-this-definition-of-continuity) gives an example of an
alternative way to define continuity.
But the application of this definition to an actual function is
(I think) at least as complicated as the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method.

I think if you want a method you can apply to any function, you need to have
enough mathematical understanding to do $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs reliably.
The alternatives will require just as much sophistication.

*For many functions,* however, you *can* avoid having to write out
the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method if you are allowed to apply a few known facts.
For example, if $f$ and $g$ are both continuous functions over the
domain $A$, then $f + g: x \mapsto f(x) + g(x)$ is also a continuous
function over the domain $A$.
There are several useful facts like this by which you can combine
known continuous functions to show that other functions are continuous;
page 2 of [this document](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~reinholz/ed/07fa_m155/lectures/continuous_functions.pdf), for example, shows some of them.

Realize that someone had to apply $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs or similarly
difficult methods in order to prove all of those facts in the first place.
But once you know they are true, they make it very easy to show that
(for example) the function $x \mapsto \frac{x^2}{x+1}$ on the domain $[0,\infty)$ is continuous.

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ is not continuous at $x=-1$. Did you mean $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$?

Comment: @Oriol OP had mentioned that particular function in a comment, but restricted to the non-negative reals. I neglected to specify the domain (my mistake, sorry!); I think that's fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

You bet there is! To prove the continuity of $y=f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ on positive reals, just show that every infinitesimal $x$-increment always leads to an infinitesimal change in $y$, which is the Cauchy-Robinson definition of continuity.  Namely, if $\alpha>0$ is infinitesimal then 
$$f(x+\alpha)-f(x)= \frac{(x+\alpha)^2}{x+\alpha+1}-\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\frac{(x+\alpha)^2(x+1)-(x+1+\alpha)x^2}{ (x+1+\alpha)(x+1) }.
$$
Multiplying out, we get
$$
f(x+\alpha)-f(x)= \frac{x^3+2x^2\alpha+\alpha^2x + x^2+2x\alpha+\alpha^2-x^3-x^2-\alpha x^2}{ (x+1+\alpha)(x+1)}.
$$
Simplifying, we get
$$
f(x+\alpha)-f(x)= \frac{2x^2\alpha+\alpha^2x +2x\alpha+\alpha^2-\alpha x^2}{(x+1+\alpha)(x+1)}=\alpha\frac{2x^2+\alpha x +2x+\alpha- x^2}{(x+1+\alpha)(x+1)}.
$$
This is a product of an infinitesimal $\alpha$ by a finite number $\frac{2x^2+\alpha x +2x+\alpha- x^2}{(x+1+\alpha)(x+1)}$ which is therefore infinitesimal. QED. For details on the rules governing manipulation with infinitesimals see [*Elementary calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Comment: This is very slick, but in the setting of a standard elementary analysis course, it’s not a proof of continuity.  It’s proving something related in a rather different setting; and there are big transfer theorems that show that this implies continuity in the standard sense.  But I wouldn’t accept this from a student as a proof of continuity in the usual setting, unless they could also demonstrate some understanding of the transfer theorems, since without those, this is a proof of something rather different.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, thanks for your comments. I have two remarks. (1) At my university, we teach first semester calculus to 130 students every year using infinitesimals a la Keisler, and this *is indeed* the definition of continuity. (2) You seem to be convinced that the epsilon-delta is the "true" definition but at any hate historically this is not accurate since the first definition was Cauchy's and it was the one I gave in my answer.  The epsilon-delta definition is a paraphrase of Cauchy's definition due to Weierstrass.  If you like I can send you a text containing a more detailed discu

Comment: Also, the OP may be engaged in self-study rather than taking a course at your university, in which case the infinitesimal approach is the more intuitive one that prepares the ground for facing the epsilon-delta paraphrases later.  At any rate the OP specifically asked for a different approach, which is what I provided.

Comment: @MK: don’t worry, I’m certainly not advocating the idea that ε-δ is the one true definition of continuity — I’m a big fan of alternative approaches to the reals and analysis.  But ε-δ (or its rephrasing in terms of open sets, or similar) is still by far the most standard approach, and it’s the one the OP mentions in their question — so I’m assuming that this is the setting they’re coming from.  I read their question as wanting an alternative way of *proving* continuity (implicitly: in the standard setting), not as asking for an alternate *definition* of the reals/continuity.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, indeed the OP asked for an alternative method of *proving* continuity. This is precisely what I provided.

Comment: +1, fun approach. @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine do you have any references to those transfer theorems? I'd love to read a bit on that, I've always been skeptical of calculus with infinitesimals a la Robinson.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, the transfer theorem is explained in detail with examples in the *Elementary Calculus* reference that I linked in my answer.  For a higher level approach I can recommend additional textbooks if you are interested.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, also, I found Alain Robert's book on (E. Nelson's IST version of) non-standard analysis eminently readable, clear, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Topologically you can argue that given two topological spaces $(A, \tau_{A}),(B, \tau_{B})$ a function is continuous if for  $f:A \to B$ we have $U \in \tau_{B} \implies f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_{A}$.

Edit:

First of all, given an arbitrary space $X$, a metric is a function $d:X \times X \to [0,\infty)$ where together the space and the metric $(X,d)$ form a metric space (and also note that a metric space is a topological space since metrics induce topologies). To be a metric, $d$ must satisfy some intuitive properties namely that 
$$d(x_{1},x_{2})=0 \implies x_{1}=x_{2}$$
and
$$
d(x_{1},x_{2})=d(x_{2},x_{1})
$$
and finally the triangle inequality
$$
d(x_{1},x_{3}) \leq d(x_{1},x_{2})+d(x_{2},x_{3})
$$
Now we usually denote the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ which for $x_{1},x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ we have just $\lvert x_{1} \rvert =d(0,x_{1})$ and $\lvert x_{1}-x_{2} \rvert=d(x_{1},x_{2})$.

Now for $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs, we have the general statement in plain English that for a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$
\lim_{x \to x_{0}}f(x)=L
$$
if for $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert x- x_{0}\rvert <\delta$ imples that $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert<\epsilon$

Now what is really going on here? Well first note that we can *choose* our value of epsilon since it is arbitrary and if $f$ is continuous, then there will be a corresponding value of $\delta$ that guarantees that $\lvert x-x_{0} \rvert<\delta$. This means that $\delta$ **IS A FUNCTION OF EPSILON**, which is the part that so many teachers do not explicitly mention, thus leading to so much confusion. Again, just to make that as explicit as possible, $\delta$ is uniquely determined by our choice of $\epsilon$. Now what exactly is $\epsilon$? Well, recall from algebra that
$$
\lvert f(x)-L \rvert<\epsilon \text{ is equivalent to writing } L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon
$$
so $\epsilon$ quantifies the degree to which we "squeeze" the interval $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$ and $\delta$ quantifies the degree to which we squeeze the interval $(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)$ based on our choice of $\epsilon$. Now, this might seem backwards since $x$ is the independent variable and the value of $f(x)$ depends on our choice of $x$ but that is actually exactly why we need this framework. Let's say we reversed the statement and we squeezed $(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)$ by choosing $\delta$ instead of epsilon, then the fact that there is some value $\epsilon$ such that $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert <\epsilon$ is trivial for *any* (bounded) function. Basically, the intuition for continuity is that continuity implies that when two values $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are "close" (an inherently topological notion) to each other then $f(x_{1})$ and $f(x_{2})$ have to be close to each other as well. Thus, by squeezing the interval $(L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon)$ then for a continuous function, we know that the interval $(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)$ will be squeezed to a distance of $\delta$ as a function of  $\epsilon$.

Now see if you can "reverse engineer" the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity to arrive at the topological definition I provided above.

Comment: Ok thank you but I think this is not easier, it seems a bit harder for me : /

Comment: There is no other easier way?

Comment: To rigorously prove continuity? I'm afraid not. Is there anything in particular that gives you so much difficulty understanding $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs?

Comment: For function I don't have problem, just show for left side and right side limit, if same then continuous.. Why not for this : /
epsilon delta work with metrics right? I don't understand anything there..

Comment: Yes with $\epsilon-\delta$ there is an implicit assumption that you are working in a metric space..I'll edit my question in a second and see if I can't break it down for you.

Comment: Continuous functions do not map open sets to open sets or closed sets to closed sets ! Take the constant function $0$ (mapping open sets to $\{ 0 \}$), or function with asymptote as $x \mapsto e^{-x}$ can map closed sets (here $[0,\infty)$) to non closed sets ($(0,1]$)

Comment: You are right, I phrased that poorly

Answer (score 0):

You could try reasoning within a framework which extends the reals with actual infinitesimals (I am aware of three such frameworks).

Comment: Welcome! You should at least spell out the names of those three :-)

Comment: Done; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there are simple ways to show continuity.

## Composition of continuous functions is continuous

If you build your function out of continuous functions, it is automatically continuous. For example, consider the function:

$$ f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x^2} $$

Constants, addition, squaring, and square roots are all continuous on their domain, and this implies $f$ is continuous.

## Compute the limit

The usual definition of continuity is not $\epsilon-\delta$: it is in terms of limits. You spend a lot of time in your calculus classes learning how to compute them.

For example, consider the function

$$ \mathrm{sinc}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin x}{x} & x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x = 0 \end{cases} $$

By the method above, we can immediately see that $\mathrm{sinc}$ is continuous whenever $x \neq 0$. To show continuity at $x=0$, we just compute the limit.

> Goal: prove $\mathrm{sinc}(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}\mathrm{sinc}(x) $

The left hand side is $1$. The right hand side can be computed by

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \mathrm{sinc}(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 $$

Both sides are equal, and so $\mathrm{sinc}$ is continuous at zero as well, so it's continuous everywhere.